# Configuring nginx to proxy thin and Rails ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, thin, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm experimenting with ActionCable (mostly replicating the [DHH example](https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples)) and trying to get it to run on an Ubuntu server with thin (on port 8443) and nginx. It all works fine locally but, when I try to proxy it on a live server I get this error response: `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301`.

Here's my the relevant bits of my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name _not_;
  root /home/ubuntu/www/;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
  server 127.0.0.1:8443;
}

server {

  listen 80;

  ...

  location /websocket/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  ...

}
```

I'm sort of out of my league with nginx here -- what am I missing or getting wrong?

Comment: Does that happen in 60sec?

Comment: @Anatoly Does it open/close in 60 seconds? It doesn't connect to the websocket at all.

Comment: I am not sure, bu I don't think your websockets server should listen to 80. Il NGINX docs, it listen to 8020.
https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this after a month and discovered that the issues were not with the nginx configuration but related to thin. I did three things:

(1) Configured thin to use [the Faye adapter](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#running-the-app-with-thin):

```
# config.ru

require 'faye'
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

use Faye::RackAdapter, mount: '/faye', timeout: 25

run Rails.application
```

(2) Switched to mounting ActionCable in `routes.rb`, rather than trying to run it [as a standalone](https://github.com/rails/actioncable#standalone).

```
#routes.rb

MyAwesomeApp::Application.routes.draw do

  ...

  match "/websocket", to: ActionCable.server, via: [:get, :post]

end
```

(3) Returned to my normal nginx configuration, the websockets upstreaming thin (as the webserver does:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close; }

upstream thin { 
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  ...

  location /websocket {
    proxy_pass http://thin;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;   }

  ...
}
```

So, my apologies nginx, I'm exonerating you -- seems the issues were primarily related to thin.

---

Edit: I've added the old nginx configuration I had returned to after mounting in the routes. Also worth noting, for those using SSL is that `config.force_ssl` will break the secure `wss` websocket. Instead, you should do `force_ssl` on the controller level, [as recommended here](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/issues/333), and configure nginx to rewrite any HTTP routes to HTTPS.

Comment: Were you able to keep the same type of nginx.conf listed in your question, when you mounted in routes.rb? (2)

Comment: @DavidKuhta Edited the answer to include the nginx config I returned to and also give an SSL tip that caused me issues.

Answer (score 1):

This thread was very helpful to me, but I elected to separate the AC process into a separate puma instance so I could configure workers, etc separately. I later added SSL proxying from nginx to ensure the latest ciphers, etc are used.  This avoids rails/puma/AC having to worry about SSL vs non-SSL; everything is non-SSL inside the server instance.

Here's my server section for AC:

```
server {
   listen 881 ssl;


   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';


   server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cable;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Note from this github [issue](https://github.com/rails/actioncable/issues/131#issuecomment-163631870): you need to ensure your AC config allows your domain as a source:

```
#config/initializers/cable.rb
ActionCable.server.config.allowed_request_origins = %w( http://my-domain.com  )
```